# Android, как сделать, чтобы виджет рабочего стола обновлялся не по интервалу от установки ,а в 12.00 ежедневно?

Tags: java, android, виджет

Имеется календарь с виджетом, отображающим дату. Установка обычного таймера на сутки обновляет во время, когда виджет был установлен на рабочий стол, а надо чтобы обновление произошло в 12.00. Идеально было бы переустановить время старта для таймера, но я не нахожу в доках можно ли это сделать, подскажите, кто знает. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Можно установить AlarmManager. При первом входе вычисляете сколько осталось до 12:00 и запускаете AlarmManager. Когда AlarmManager сработает снова вычисляете сколько времени осталось до 12:00 и снова запускаете его. Надеюсь вы поняли логику. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager

Comment: Да, я тоже сразу про AlarmManager подумала, но  надеялась, что может быть есть какой-то встроенный функционал.Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Как-то не очень, направление дали хорошее, но в итоге только запутали. Ведь такой подход сложен и очень ресурсоёмок.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того что таймер это плохо, по многим причинам, потому `AlarmManager` есть отличный вариант, для вас он можносказать идеальный, да много муторни, но он будет экономить заряд как нельзя кстати. Если же в 12:00 телефон будет спать то скорее всего он не проснётся, а `AlarmManager` сработает при просыпании телефона. Это всё настраивается. А теперь о действиях:

При первом входе создаём аларм менеджер и передаём ему время вычесленное от сейчас, я для этих целей использовал DateTime (JodaTime): `DateTime.now().withTime(12,0,0,0).millis`,
таким образом вы получаете время следующего срабатывания в миллисекундах, при срабатывании ставите прмерно также: `DateTime.now().plusDays(1).withTime(12,0,0,0).millis`.

Учтите, что нужно будет настроить BroadcastReceiver, который переустановит AlarmManager после перезагрузки, хотя не знаю, нужно проверить, мб это можно сделать прямо в виджете.

Теперь о косяках, мог где-то ошибиться. И не помню точно, но при первом варианте, после двенадцати нужно будет добавлять день.

О бонусах: `DateTime.now().withTime(12,0,0,0).millis - DateTime.now().millis` вы получите значение которое можно отдать таймеру. Вы же помните, таймер это плохо!?

P.S. А вообще, если хорошо порыться то и проще реализацию можно реализовать.